# Replace multiline text in file using regex on Linux

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed

I need to replace multiline text in config file.
I can use sed (BusyBox v1.21.1), perl (revision 5 version 14 subversion 2) or python (2.7).

The file can have two formats:
A)

```
     "is_managed": false,
      "local_profile_id": 15191724,
      "name": "First user"
    },
    **"session": {
      "restore_on_startup": 4,
      "restore_on_startup_migrated": true,
      "urls_to_restore_on_startup": [ "http://alamakota/" ]
    }**
}
```

or 
B)

```
      "is_managed": false,
      "local_profile_id": 15191724,
      "name": "First user"
   },
   **"session": {
      "restore_on_startup_migrated": true,
   }**
}
```

I want to change it to look like this:

```
     "is_managed": false,
      "local_profile_id": 15191724,
      "name": "First user"
   },
   "session": {
      "restore_on_startup": 4,
      "restore_on_startup_migrated": true,
      "urls_to_restore_on_startup": [ "http://192.168.0.100" ]
   }
}
```

Comment: So are the changes that you want: to remove `*` from around the "session" part, and convert hostnames to IPs?  Might there be many hostnames in that list?  In the B) example where there is not a `urls_to_restore_on_startup` entry what did you want to have happen?

Comment: This looks like JSON. Is it JSON? If it is JSON, you don't want to do this with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to parse it as json first and encode back to json if needed

```
use JSON::XS;

my $rh_data = decode_json($json_string);

#then updated values by accesing $rh_data->{xx}{yy} = 'new value';

#and encode back to json
$json_data  = encode_json($rh_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(my $ln = <STDIN>){
    if ($ln =~ /^([ ]*)(\*\*)(.*)/) {
        print "$1"."$3";
    } elsif ($ln =~ /(.*)?(\*\*)([ ]*)$/) {
        print "$1"."$3";
    } else {
        print $ln;
    }
}
```

try running it as 
    `perl program.pl < input.txt`

Comment: This is only to remove `**`, i’m not sure what exactly you want. but this will only help with the `**` as mentioned in other comments you have to use JSON parsers if its JSON and also some more logic to resolve hostname to IP